# How to get the foreign key in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing StudentApp in .NET 3.5 SP1 MVC Application.

I have two tables

1. Course
       CourseID, course_Name
2. Students
       studentID, student_Name, courseID(fk)

Now I made StudentApp.dbml which is having both table as entities.

As Foreign key will not be present in student entity,
I can not display courseID in student model, more over i can not generate add, edit, list views.

So tell me how to display courseID(fk) in student & i also want course name instead.

And also dropdownbox showing course name & storing courseID in edit view .

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Entity Framework?  DBML mapping files are for Linq to Sql

Comment: ops you were right it was Entity Framework

Comment: Please edit the question so that it makes sense, then. L2S and EF handle foreign keys *completely* differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using LINQ-to-SQL and created a DBML file in Visual Studio then the foreign keys can be listed through the `Course` property in the `Student` object (automatically generated so since it is a one-to-many relationship from `Student`). Sort of like this:

```
var studentCourseIds =
    from s in context.Students
    select s.Course.CourseID;
```

Since your goal is to find the coursename then it is already accessible with `Student.Course.course_Name`.

Comment: ya thanks.
I already used LINQ to SQL class.
My objective is to display Student object in a view that list all record.
so where i put above code, as i am using MVC architecture..?

Comment: Vikas: It depends on what strategy you use with your MVC. In my MVC I create repository class (it is a Repository pattern thing) in the model that returns stuff in general that I want from the database. And then I have a service class that further filters what I want from the repository.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to load the foreign reference for each entity. Since I have no idea how you've constructed your API, I'll have to give you a pseudocode'ish example, but I think this is what you need to do.

```
List<Students> studList = [your_db_facade].SelectStudents() // Or however you retrieve your students

foreach (Students singleStudent in studList)
    singleStudent.Context.CourseReference.Load() //CourseReference.Load() should be in the framework
```

Then you get the CourseID and name from the single student entity like

```
singleStudent.Course.CourseID
singleStudent.Course.course_Name
```

It could look slightly different for you, but I think the key to solving your problem is CourseReference.Load().

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your DBML?  Also, DBML is used in LINQ to SQL (L2S) - EDMX is the mapping used in the ADO Entity Framework.  Are you using LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework (EF)?

No matter which one you are using - they both support Foreign Keys and you would get a property representing either side of the relationship - you don't need to do anything special (the Foreign Key must exist in the database, of course).

In EF, the foreign  keys are called "navigtion properties" and they work a little differently to Foreign Keys in L2S.  Nothing major, but updating them and "eager loading" are somewhat different.

Just drop the tables onto the map in the designer in Visual Studio (or generate using command line equivalents if you prefer).

Regarding Foreign Keys and Drop Down Lists (and other UI goodness) - I wrote a couple of blog entries on some approaches which might suit you.  One part is located [here](http://internationalized.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!43F3A7682D1564E4!1192.entry) and part two is located [here](http://internationalized.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!43F3A7682D1564E4!1216.entry).

Comment: StudentApp.dbml  is an Entity data model.
so in student table courseID will not have a mapping.
Mapping is considered as an association.

more over
i am using MVC architecture.
i add a Index view of student so it will inherit from StudentApp.model
 which is auto generated class by Entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

if you create the correct relationship in your SQL server database, then when you add the tables to your DBML designer, the relationships will be copied across also and your code will link up automatically.